# Virtual Directory htaccess and url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website in php which has some pages:

```
www.example.com/news
www.example.com/people
www.example.com/music
```

On each of these pages is an overview of content. If you click, for example, on a link on www.example.com/news, an article opens with that url using a template `(www.example.com/article.php?url='example-of-article-url')`

For each of these pages there is a rewrite needed. The displayed url should be www.example.com/news/example-of-article-url
and this should acces the article.php file. The news directory is virtual. The www.example.com/news, www.example.com/people, www.example.com/music are being rewritten by this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

What I have been trying is:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*) article.php?url='$1' [R=301,L]
```

However, when this is loaded, css and images aren't. The content is generated thinking it's in the /news/ directory, thus unable to find the other files. I can't use canonical URL's because of SEO-reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add:

```
<base href="/"/>
```

In your `<head>`section.

Answer (score 1):

First of all dont forget to add this at the very start:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Remove the Qoutes from '$1' your last line and try the method below instead.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect with the contents of a whole directory to your location:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

**Or you can do it this way too with a Slash on the Start:**

Redirect the whole folder (news) to your new location:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?news/(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/news/(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect with the contents of a whole directory to your location:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/news/(.*)$ article.php?url=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Best of Luck